# Strange SQL Syntax error

Tags: php, mysql, sql

With a the code,

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO Messages (Message, toUser, From, Date) VALUES ('$mes','$to','$from','$date')")
```

I'm getting an SQL syntax error. What is the reason for this? I see nothing wrong with the syntax.

Comment: What does the error say?

Comment: Probably depends on the PHP interpolation. Show us the _actual_ MySQL query: breaking a problem down to its smallest component part is a _key_ element of debugging.

Comment: And, as an aside, but an important one: take a look at [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Comment: Usually when you get an error in such a simple one-liner, the specific error doesn't say much else valuable than 'syntax error'.

Comment: My guess is someone put a `'` inside one of the variables.

Comment: @Raidohh: It does tell you where exactly it is in that line, and that's the most important bit.

Comment: @BoltClock: You're right. The error I got when I tried was the following: `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'From, Date) VALUES ('a','b','c','d')' at line 1`. I for some reason thought it printed out the whole row..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`DATE` is a reserved word in SQL, so I gather that it's triggering a syntax error when you use it as a column name because MySQL tries to parse it as something other than a column name.

Either escape your identifiers with backticks:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `Messages` (`Message`, `toUser`, `From`, `Date`) VALUES ('$mes','$to','$from','$date')")
```

Or better, see if you can rename the column to something else that doesn't need escaping.

Comment: +1: Best to delimit the lot! At least make it consistent.

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal: Heh, of course - fixed :)

Comment: `Date` may be an SQL keyword, but I've never had an issue with not having it in backticks in a field list before.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is someone put a `'` in one of the variables, thus making a query like

```
INSERT INTO Messages (Message, toUser, From, Date) VALUES ('Test','Joe O'Neil','Jack Smith','2011-12-20')
```

This is a syntax error because of the `'` in `"O'Neil"`.  You need to escape your variables before using them in SQL.

```
$mes = mysql_real_escape_string($mes);
$to = mysql_real_escape_string($to);
$from = mysql_real_escape_string($from);
$date = mysql_real_escape_string($date);
mysql_query("INSERT INTO Messages (Message, toUser, From, Date) VALUES ('$mes','$to','$from','$date')");
```

Answer (score 0):

Make your query, like:

```
//use mysql_real_escape_string for variables
mysql_query("INSERT INTO Messages (`Message`, `toUser`, `From`, `Date`) VALUES ('$mes','$to','$from','$date')")
```

Answer (score 0):

There's probably a character in your variables that requires escaping. Use `mysql_real_escape_string` as described here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php